# Exporting Eclipse RAP war with OSGi bundles with external bundle-path

Tags: eclipse, export, osgi, eclipse-rap

I have an Eclipse RAP product, I like to export as a web app for use inside Tomcat. For this I use the warproduct exporter in Eclipse, which until now have worked fine.

I have a problem with compilation of one of the OSGi bundles in the product as this refers to a set of external jars using a variable substitution. This is shown in the following fragment from a `MANIFEST.MF`:

```
Bundle-Name: ...
Bundle-SymbolicName: ...
Bundle-ClassPath2: external:/A/test1/jakarta-tomcat/shared/lib/a_base.jar
Bundle-ClassPath: external:$A_HOME$/jakarta-tomcat/shared/lib/a_base.jar
```

If I use the first classpath instead and have the correct `/A/test1/jakarta-tomcat/shared/lib/a_base.jar` in place, then everything is fine during the compilation... And I can even manually change the `MANIFEST.MF` afterwards to the correct version with the substitution.

But, I would really like to avoid this extra step, if at all possible!

I think the question is how to pass in a proper value for `A_HOME` during the compilation?

(Why do this? Above, I just shown a single jar file, but we have a larger number of jar files we want to share between our older Tomcat applications and the newer RAP based application. We know, there are other ways of sharing jars in this situation - e.g. via an OSGi framework extender or the `extendedFrameworkExports` initialization parameter in `web.xml` - but we need the chosen method as we use EMF and therefore cannot share the EMF meta data between Tomcat and Eclipse... And thus not the class objects...)

Comment: Now reported as https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=372945

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this feature is currently not support within the WAR Products Tooling. I recommend to open a bug against Eclipse Libra and to define the feature request their. Anyway, we have created an example how to build a RAP application with tycho which is pretty easy, maybe you want to take a look: https://github.com/eclipsesource/rap-mobile-demos

Cheers Holger